# Text in WordPress not rendering correctly in Chrome

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I made a form on my WordPress site that listed a few options. When viewing the website in Chrome the text doesn't render correctly, however, it renders correctly when viewing the page via Internet Explorer.

[image]

Not too sure for the reasoning behind this. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: Encoding would be my best guess - you'd get better help if you posted a real example...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the default font on your computer might have been overwritten expecially if your font is georgia, I most times have this problem as well, i think what you should do is find another machine running your version of chrome, preferably newly formatted without font installation and test the page. also check the encoding, [utf_8(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML) is the browser standard

[This thread might show you how to change character encoding](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-the-character-encoding)

[Her is another resource that might help](http://blogsuccessjournal.com/blog-tips-and-advice/wordpress-tips-advice/seeing-weird-characters-on-blog-how-to-fix-wordpress-character-encoding-latin1-to-utf8/)

Comment: Interesting. Well the encoding is definitely utf-8, but you're right about it rendering correctly on other computers. Seems to just be mine. Is there anyway I could ensure the text is displayed correctly if the issue is in fact the system's default font?

Comment: Ok, what i do is, before I try to install any font on my computer, I try to create a backup of what i have there (i use windows). I'm pretty sure the font you are talking about is Georgia, have a backup of it or try download another one (ttf format). If it is not georgia, locate the font your system is running by using the browser inspect and try download a fresh copy. Use `firefox` with web developer tool as well, if this helps, mark it as answer. have fun